# MDL card doesn't align on top of parent

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I use the mdl framework for designing my webapp.

```
<div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--top mdl-cell--6-col">
...
<div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--top mdl-cell--6-col">
...
<div ng-init="showLmsSwitch()" class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell  mdl-cell--6-col  mdl-cell--top">
...
```

These are the three cards which are displayed in the picture.

[image: Webapp]

The last one on the bottom (steuerung logitech media server) has the class `mdl-cell--top` so it should align on the top of the parent, but it doesn't.
Anybody knows why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you used `mdl-layout` or `mdl-grid` components and how? You need to show more code, to understand how cards are positioned. You can use [this blank template](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/jLQOXR) to post your code (just add html/css).

Comment: @KostasSiabanis i forked your mdl template: https://codepen.io/hiabst/pen/YxRXwb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three cards in your layout are in the same 'row', so when the first one gets 6 columns (of the available 12 of each row) and the second one gets the other 6 columns, your third card gets another 6 columns but has already been pushed to the next row.

You have to use multiple `mdl-grid` components to achieve this layout:

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-grid mdl-cell--6-col">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">Content</div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-cell--6-col">Content
  </div>
</div>
```

I have updated your pen [here](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/EvOjmd).